# Very slow inserts into a SQLite Database (VB.NET, LINQ2SQL)

Tags: database, vb.net, sqlite, linq-to-sql

I have a problem with very slow inserts into my database in my application.
Application uses

- SQLite Database
- VB.NET
- Linq To SQL

It is a simple insert of about 600 records with 4 fields. That's all. It takes about 10 seconds in my Dell Vostro with Intel Core 2 Duo computer. I think it should be lot faster and I cannot figure it out.

The table is not indexed. There is one primary key autoincrement field, another Id field which references a foreign table (1234 below)
Here is my code:

```
Using dc = Utility.GetNewDataContext
            Dim myList As New List(Of myData)
            For Each pt As CapturedDataPoint In _capturedDataPoints
                Dim rec As New myData
                rec.Id = 1234 
                rec.captureTimeSec = pt.captureTimeSec
                rec.force = pt.force
                rec.displacement = pt.displacement
                myList.Add(rec)
            Next
            dc.myData.InsertAllOnSubmit(myList)
            dc.SubmitChanges()
end using
```

To time the operations I have a Stopwatch object and print ElapsedTimeMilliseconds
Before the above code, I have 2 other inserts (one record each) and a delete (one record). Each of these 3 operations takes approx 0.6 sec. Granted 10 seconds for the 600 inserts is better than 600*.6=36 seconds, but I have the feeling it should be a lot faster.

Comment: Is the database on a network location?

Answer (score 0):

It must be due to this limitation:

> Transaction speed is limited by the rotational speed of your disk drive. - [from sqlite faq](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19)